# Maglor in the Third Age?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

would it be possible for Maglor to be in Middle Earth during this time? for example perhaps he wandered across the Blue Mountains at the end of the first age staying along the coastline or somewhere out of contact with anyone preferably somewhere along the Coast of Southern Gondor and just grieves with sadness about the loss of the Silmaril sings lament about it.

What do you think is this a possible scenario for Maglor or do we just assume he died

Comment: That is definitely an interesting theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

From *The Silmarillion*, "Quenta Silmarillion: Of the Voyage of Eärendil and the War of Wrath" (emphasis mine):

> he wandered **ever** upon the shores [...] Legend says that he **still wanders the shores of the World**, singing laments for his despair and regret.